# How the get the same number of page in the table of content as the page number is inside the document?

Tags: r, bookdown, tableofcontents

I'm using R package bookdown to write my thesis, I do not know how but the page numbers from table of contents are different from the actual page numbers of the document.

[image: from toc]

[image: chapter 4]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Which output format do you use (PDF. DOCX, ...)?

Comment: I used pdf output. Sorry, I've no minimal example. If you want I can try to add here some screen-shots from the toc and the document page. Is it possible this issue is due to a lot of quotes in the documents?

Comment: Many quotes should not lead to that. Without example I can only guess: LaTeX needs several runs to get the page numbers in the TOC correct. Maybe rmarkdown does not recognize this properly in your case. Test: add `keep_tex: yes` to the output YAML section. Process the resulting PDF file with `pdflatex` (and `bibtex`) until there are no messages like "... has changed, rerun LaTeX ...".

Comment: `keep_tex: yes` is already there, after changing from Xelatex to pdflatex I'm getting a fatal error due to latex package fontspec. According to the error message, fontspec need Xelatex.

Comment: That's the problem with missing example ... Anyway, don't change your document and process the TEX file with `xelatex`.

Comment: @RalfStubner, I'm sorry being not able to provide an example. Using Xelatex, I am getting this raised issue. Interestingly, in every next chapter heading or section or sub-section heading the gap of number of pages is just keep on increasing.

Comment: Please process the TEX file directly with `xelatex` and post the output of that command.

Comment: `Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.`

Comment: `! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179814/discussion-between-ralf-stubner-and-koliii).